# How do I filter overlayed WAR resources when building a WAR with Maven?

Tags: resources, filter, maven, overlay, pom.xml

I have two WARS:

1. base-overlay
2. example-app

base-overlay has XML config files in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/*.xml`.  In those XML config files, I have parameters that need to be filtered when building the example-app WAR, which depends on base-overlay to be its overlay.  For example, `base-overlay/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/app-context.xml` has `${data.url}` in it.  When packaging the example-app WAR, I've set the POM property `<data.url>http://example.com:1234</data.url>` to replace base-overlay's `${data.url}`.

When I configure the maven-war-plugin to filter this file, I had to give it a directory of `target/war/work/com.example/base-overlay/WEB-INF/spring` just to find the `app-config.xml` file to filter before adding it to the newly packaged example-app WAR.  This seems like a hack, and also doesn't work when testing with Jetty, as the WAR isn't created and filtered.

Furthermore, the POM's `<build/>` element has a `<resources/>` element, but I couldn't get that to work.

How do I filter the overlay resources when compiling?

Comment: Perhaps you should post the relevant pom snippet of example-app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue, I moved all XML resources (Spring) to the appropriate Maven resource directory `${basedir}\src\main\resources\` and then added that to the POM in the `<build/>` element like:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

I included the common XML resources that don't need to be filtered the in the base-overlay WAR. In each application that uses the base-overlay WAR, I added an XML file named `filtered-resources.xml` that is filtered each time the application WAR is packaged and assembled by Jetty.